# Type hinting for functions in Clojure

Tags: java, reflection, function, clojure, type-hinting

I'm trying to resolve a reflection warning in Clojure that seems to result from the lack of type inference on function return values that are normal Java objects.

Trivial example code that demonstrates the issue:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)    

(defn foo [#^Integer x] (+ 3 x))

(.equals (foo 2) (foo 2))

=> Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:10 - call to equals can't be resolved.
   true
```

What is the best way to solve this? Can this be done with type hints?

Comment: What version of Clojure are you using? I tried your example in my Clojure v1.0 and it seems to work fine...

Comment: It's a clojure 1.2 build. Note that the warning only shows with (set! *warn-on-reflection* true) which may be the difference.... edited the question to make clearer

Comment: Yes, that was it. I see it now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These two versions appear to work:

```
user> (defn foo [^Integer x] (+ 3 x))
#'user/foo
user> (.equals (foo 2) (foo 2))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 - call to equals can't be resolved.  ;'
true
user> (.equals ^Integer (foo 2) ^Integer (foo 2))
true
user> (defn ^Integer foo [^Integer x] (+ 3 x))
#'user/foo
user> (.equals (foo 2) (foo 2))
true
```

Note that type hinting is still a bit in flux in Clojure right now leading up to the 1.2 release, so this might not work the same way forever.  Note also that `#^` is deprecated in favor of `^`.

Comment: Great, works perfectly thanks! Also good to know about the changing syntax... the joys of living on the cutting edge I guess :-)

Comment: that's great! looking forward to speed up my code using this :)