# What is the difference between these type hinting forms and why is when implemented as an if statement?

Tags: clojure

I'm new in clojure so I would like to know some things

There are 2 ways to typehint your code, I would like to know the difference

```
^String and others using #^String
```

When I saw the code from **when** I was a little disappointed, it's an **if** if that is not true could explain me why (**assert** is a **when** with **throw**)

```
(defmacro when
  "Evaluates test. If logical true, evaluates body in an implicit do."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [test & body]
  (list 'if test (cons 'do body)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [`#^` is the old, deprecated syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245540/clojure-type-hints-syntax) Just use `^` now going forward, unless you're running a very old version of Clojure (pre-1.2).
2. Why be disappointed? This is part of the beauty of languages like Clojure! `when` ***is*** just defined in terms of `if`. It looks like a language construct, but it's actually just a macro that anyone can write. `when` literally turns into an `if` with a `do` at compile time. It would arguably complicate the language to have made `when` a special form when it's entirely possible to define it in terms of existing forms.

   The purpose of `when` is to carry out side effects when the condition holds, but do nothing otherwise. It's simply a readability helper. It's similar to the `if-not`, and `when-not` macros that just turn into `if`s with their condition negated. They aren't *necessary* by any means, but they certainly help clean up code.

Comment: I was not aware of the new `#^Hint` way. Do you have a link to the change?

Comment: @nha `#^` is the old, deprecated way. The best reference I can find d mentioning it is the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018911/3000206. By the time I started using Clojure 2 years ago, `#^` was already deprecated, so I never used it.

Comment: @nha Nvm, found another reference. Updated the answer.

Comment: @RafaelCustódio Np. Glad to help.

Comment: Not the point of the topic, I'm new at funcional, clojure is the pilot, and I'm falling for it, it's fantastic!!! (Not the case but ir is extremely fast)

Comment: @RafaelCustódio Ya, Clojure's great. If you decide you really like functional programming, and want to try hardcore FP, try Haskell. It takes everything to the extreme. It's not a very practical language for most people because it intentionally makes some things harder, but it's a great way to see the polar opposite of classical imperative programming. I'd say make sure you know Clojure well though before moving on. Being familiar with concepts like immutability will definitely help you later.